# MaterialUI - How to apply useStyle() and normal classes in the same className attribute

Tags: reactjs, class, styles, material-ui

I'm using MaterialUI in my React Project and I want to use a useStyle() classes and a regular class in my component. Maybe the code will explain it better:

```
...

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
   fontSizeGrid: {
      fontSize: 12,
   },
}));

...

const classes = useStyles();

...


<Typography className="my-auto font-weight-bold {classes.fontSizeGrid}">Test!</Typography>

...
```

The example above doesn't' work, because it puts everything on "string mode". How can I achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

```js
<Typography className="my-auto font-weight-bold" classes={{root: classes.fontSizeGrid}}>Test!</Typography>
```

Material-UI Typography API: https://material-ui.com/es/api/typography/

> classes (object): Override or extend the styles applied to the component. See CSS API below for more details.

Comment: try now, sorry.